# Form data is always overwriting with the newly entered form value

Tags: angular, angular7

I need to store all the form value what we have entered in the form in local storage. For that i am setting the form values and pushing the form values after getting that form data. But when i tried to push the data it is always replacing with newly entered form data. I need all the form values in my component. How can i do that?

**input.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="messageForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="initiativename" formControlName="initiativename">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="yearoflaunch" formControlName="yearoflaunch">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="country" formControlName="country">
</form>
```

**input.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { DataService } from "src/app/earlysizing/data.service"

import { LocalStorageService, SessionStorageService, LocalStorage, SessionStorage } from 'angular-web-storage';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-input',
  templateUrl: './input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input.component.scss']
})
export class inputComponent implements OnInit {
  messageForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private _emp: DataService;
    public local: LocalStorageService,
    public session: SessionStorageService
  ) {  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.messageForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      initiativename: ['', [Validators.required],
      yearoflaunch: ['', Validators.required],
      country: ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
    if (this.messageForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }
    else{
      this.local.set('inputs', {...this.messageForm.value});
    }
  }
}
```

**existing.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from 'src/app/earlysizing/data.service';
import { LocalStorageService, SessionStorageService, LocalStorage, SessionStorage } from 'angular-web-storage';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-existing',
  templateUrl: './existing.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./existing.component.scss']
})

export class ExistingForecastComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _emp : DataService, private local: LocalStorageService, private session: SessionStorageService) { }

  private existingForecasts : any = [];


  ngOnInit() {
      this._emp.setMyGV('Existing Forecast');
      const sessionData = this.local.get('inputSelections');
      console.log('sessionData',sessionData);
      this.pushData(sessionData);
    }

    pushData(x:any)
    {
      this.existingForecasts.push(x);
      console.log('existingForecasts',this.existingForecasts);
    }

}
```

**existing.component.html:**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Initiative Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Country</th>
        <th scope="col">Year Of Launch</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let e of existing">
      <td>{{e.initiativename}}</td>
      <td>{{e.country}}</td>
      <td>{{e.yearoflaunch}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Here this.existing is always replaced with newly entered form data. I need to store all the data we entered in the form many times. How to do that? What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you navigated to **existing.component.ts**, It rendered newly. i.e, `existingForecasts` property will become an empty Array. So, when you push the values from the localStorage, only the new values will be available. To solve this issue, you can use **Services** which are **singleton objects**

For instance, I am going to use one of your service called `DataService`. In your `DataService`, i am going to declare a property

**data.service.ts**

`public existingForecasts: any = [];`

**existing.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from 'src/app/earlysizing/data.service';
import { LocalStorageService, SessionStorageService, LocalStorage, SessionStorage } from 'angular-web-storage';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-existing',
  templateUrl: './existing.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./existing.component.scss']
})

export class ExistingForecastComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _emp : DataService, private local: LocalStorageService, private session: SessionStorageService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
      this._emp.setMyGV('Existing Forecast');
      const sessionData = this.local.get('inputSelections');
      console.log('sessionData',sessionData);
      this.pushData(sessionData);
    }

    pushData(x:any) {
      this._emp.existingForecasts.push(x);
      console.log('existingForecasts',this._emp.existingForecasts);
    }

}
```

Comment: Still it is overriding

Comment: can you share your full code both componen.html and componen.ts.

Comment: It is a very long code. But the main thing is that only

Comment: Share your code, so that i can help you. Or create a stackblitz

Comment: I am getting the form data. but it is overriding. The main thing goes here only. Please check it once.

Comment: when will this code execute `this.local.set('input', this.messageForm.value);`

Comment: if the form is validated correctly it will executes. I am getting all the form data in my component. But when i am pushing it is replacing with the existing one. I have no problem with setting and getting data. I have an issue with overriding only

Comment: Whenever the component renders, this.existing is created with an empty array that's why it's not working as you expected. only if you show us full code, we can solve it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188988/discussion-between-sai-chaitanya-and-bear-nithi).

Comment: I Updated it. Please verify and help me out

Answer (score 0):

You should declare an array and push the newly entered form entry data

```
var existing = [];

existing.push(newData);
```

Comment: I declared it as   private existingForecasts : any = []; in my TS file. But it is not working